# The generating series of the weighted species of fixpoints

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, species

I am wondering if the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{D_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}t^k\right)X^n$$
where $D_m$ is the number of derangements of $m$ letters, admits a representation in closed form $f(t,X)$ for some function $f$.

This doesn't seem too difficult a problem, but I have no experience in tricks on summing series, past a few baby examples.

A bit of context: let $S^u$ be the weighted species (3.1 [here](https://bergeron.math.uqam.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/book.pdf)) assigning to an $n$-set $[n]$ the symmetric group on $n$ letters $S_n$, and equipped with the weight function $u : S_n \to \mathbb Z[t]$ sending a permutation $\sigma$ to the monomial $ t^{\mathrm{fix}\,\sigma}$ where fix of a permutation is the number of elements that $\sigma$ fixes, i.e. the cardinality of the maximum subset over which it acts as the identity.

The series above is the generating series
$$
F_{S_u}(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|S_u[n]\|\frac{X^n}{n!}
$$
where $\|S_u[n]\| := \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} u(\sigma)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} t^{\mathrm{fix}\,\sigma}$. Clearly, this is a polynomial in $t$ that reduces to $\sum_{k=0}^n N_kt^k$, where $N_k$ is the number of permutations having $k$ fixpoints. Clearly, $N_k = \binom nk D_{n-k}$, because one is choosing a $k$-subset of $[n]$ (the fixpoints), and a derangement of its complement.

Hence the series in the opening. I have tried a few tricks, but I feel like I'm shooting in the dark. A few observations:

- A similar computation with the same species $[n]\mapsto S_n$, but a different weight function $w : \sigma\mapsto t^{\mathrm{cyc}\,\sigma}$ (t raised to the number of cycles of $\sigma$) is possible using the cycle index polynomial of the symmetric group -difficult to compute, but in the specific case of $Z(S_n;t,t^2,t^3,\dots)$ the computation simplifies considerably. Is a similar approach possible here? Is there an analogue of the cycle index polynomial for fixpoints?
- A slick way to compute the generating series of $S_w$ above is to recognize that it is the plethystic substitution of the species of sets $E$ into the weighted species of cycles $C_t$, sending each cyclic order on $[n]$ to the same monomial $t$. Multiplicativity of the association $H_w\mapsto F_{H_w}(X)$, i.e. the fact that $F_{H_w\circ K_u}(X)=F_{H_w}(F_{K_u}(X))$ yields a nice closed formula for $F_{S_w}$. Is a similar approach possible here?

**Edit**. It seems that the answer was indeed *very* elementary, and I failed to see it. The series can be easily reshaped in
$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{p+q=n}\frac{D_p}{p!}\frac{t^q}{q!}\right)X^n$$
which is the Cauchy product of two simpler series. One is $e^{tX}$; the other is the series $\sum_p\frac{D_p}{p!}X^p$: to simplify the second, it's enough to know that $p!D_p = \sum_{r+s=p}\frac{(-1)^r}{r!}1^s$ is another Cauchy product.

Sadly, I was bamboozled by indices and pedices.

Comment: (Possibly, it was a mistake posting this on MathOverflow: if it is too elementary a question please feel free to migrate it to MSE. I just see that combinatorial species are a somewhat niche topic!)

Comment: Putting $j = n-k$, it looks like $\left(\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac1{k!} t^k X^k\right)\left(\sum_{j \geq 0} \frac{D_j X^j}{j!}\right)$, which is $e^{tX} \frac{e^{-X}}{1 - X}$.

Comment: Embarassingly easy. Thank you, Todd. I really have to take a bite at generatingfunctionology...

Comment: So, after all it's just the Cauchy product of two simpler series? Hm, I wonder why I didn't notice...

Comment: Generatingfunctionology is a lot of fun, more so to play than as a spectator sport. Also, you taught me a new word: pedice/pedices. I found that in an Italian-English dictionary. The top hit from Google that I got, though, directed me to Wiktionary, and while I'm always glad to learn new things, what I learned there is essentially unrepeatable here. (The singular is pēdīcō, which the curious can look up.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble indeed classic Latin is extremely rich, detailed and thorough in that field. A great reference is N.J.Adams' "The Latin Sexual Vocabulary",

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks for this! You never know when this stuff will come in handy. Jim Stasheff (https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/mathematical_emotion.html#c029928) told a story once: "but the worst was: i had picked up the math expression `to bugger a construction’
while at Princeton and used it in a lecture in Oxford with JHCW in the audience. He felt compelled to explain to me in Latin! the British meaning" (I guess you know, that's J.H.C. Whitehead).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
\text{diagonal 4} \\
\phantom{\text{diagonal 4}}\searrow \\ & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\ & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ \\ & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ \\ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \circ \\ \text{row 0 } \longrightarrow & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \bullet \\ & \uparrow \\ \qquad \text{column}
& 0
\end{array}
$$
In "diagonal 4" above, the coordinates are: 
 $\qquad (0,4),$ then $(1,3),$ then $(2,2),$ then $(3,1),$ then $(4,0).$

The sum of terms corresponding to positions in that diagonal is $\displaystyle \sum_{k\,=\,0}^4 a_{k,4-k}.$

\begin{align}
& \sum_{n\,=\,0}^\infty \sum_{k\,=\,0}^n a_{n-k,k}
= \sum_{j\,\ge\,0,\,\,\ell\,\ge\,0} a_{j,\ell}
= \sum_{j\,\ge\,0} \sum_{\ell\,\ge\,0} a_{j,\ell} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{j\,\ge\,0} \sum_{\ell\,\ge\,0} b_j c_\ell
\text{ if $a_{j,\ell}$ can be factored in that way} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{j\,\ge\,0} \left( \sum_{\ell\,\ge\,0} b_j c_\ell \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{j\,\ge\,0} \left( b_j \sum_{\ell\,\ge\,0} c_\ell \right) \\
& \text{since $b_j$ does not change as $\ell$ changes} \\[8pt]
= {} & \left( \sum_{j\,\ge\,0} b_j \right) \left( \sum_{\ell\,\ge\,0} c_\ell \right) \\
& \text{since the second sum does not change as $j$ changes.}
\end{align}